# How to use nested % printing format with exec in Python?

Tags: python, string, printing, formatting

I am not sure if the question title is intuitive, but let me explain it here in detail.

I would like to use `exec` with `for` loop to efficiently write code with repeating patterns. To illustrate, here is a very simple example

```py
channels = {'q_qp': 0, 'q_qbp': 1, 'q_q': 2, 'q_qb': 3, 'q_g': 4, 'g_g': 5}

for channel in channels:
    string = """\
print '%s'
""" % channel
    exec string
```

This is working perfectly, but the tricky part comes in when I was trying to add a formatted printing within the variable `string`, here it is

```py
import time

channels = {'q_qp': 0, 'q_qbp': 1, 'q_q': 2, 'q_qb': 3, 'q_g': 4, 'g_g': 5}

for channel in channels:
    string = """\
print '%s'
nt = time.time()
print 'now the cpu time is %f' % nt
""" % channel
    exec string
```

Apparently the `%` in the second `print` statement is causing confusion to the compiler. I tried to use `%%` instead for `string` to interpret it literally as percent sign, but it would not choose to do so.

I am wondering how this nested formatted printing could be implemented in Python, could someone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: tried `print 'now the cpu time is %%f' %% nt` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print 'now the cpu time is %%f' %% nt
```

should work fine.

But you could use `format` to avoid doubling the `%` signs:

```
string = """\
print '{}'
nt = time.time()
print 'now the cpu time is %f' % nt
""".format(channel)
```

The "game" is to use the best formatting according to the characters your string contains. In your case you don't use `{}` much so `format` is the best way.